# Getting a " Cannot GET /" when attempting to retrieve a json object from a node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am writing a RESTful API. IT runs on node.js using the express.js framework, mongodb using mongoose as the object modelling tool & body-parser to pass the http. Everytime I start the server & navigate to the specified IP address, I get a "CANNOT GET/" error. How can I can around this? Some advice would be much appreciated .

I have tired using a different port number but the problem still persists.
Here is a copy of my server.js code:

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
IP = process.env.IP,
port = process.env.PORT || 8080 ,
mongoose = require('mongoose'),
tasks = require('./api/models/todosModel'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser');

//handiling of promise 
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/Todosdb',{ useNewUrlParser: true });

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true})); // telling the sever instance to use body parser
app.use(bodyParser.json()); 

var Routes = require('./api/routes/todoRoutes');
//passing the server instance to the routes 
Routes(app);

app.listen(port,IP);
console.log("The TODO API server is running on IP: " + IP + " and port: " + port);
```

The todoRoute code :

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(app){
    var todofunctions = require('../controllers/todoController');

    // todo routes
    app.route('/tasks')      //task [GET (all the tasks),POST]
        .get(todofunctions.listTasks)
        .post(todofunctions.createTask);

    app.route('/tasks/:taskId')  //a task [GET(single task),PUT,DELETE]
        .put(todofunctions.updatetask)
        .get(todofunctions.readTask)
        .delete(todofunctions.deleteTask);

};
```

Comment: Where is the `/` route setup, ie `app.get('/',...)`? If its inside todoRoutes show that code

Comment: this is what is on my todosRoute ```'use strict';
module.exports = function(app){
    var todofunctions = require('../controllers/todoController');

    // todo routes
    app.route('/tasks')      //task [GET (all the tasks),POST]
        .get(todofunctions.listTasks)
        .post(todofunctions.createTask);

    app.route('/tasks/:taskId')  //a task [GET(single task),PUT,DELETE]
        .put(todofunctions.updatetask)
        .get(todofunctions.readTask)
        .delete(todofunctions.deleteTask);

};
```

Comment: Dont put code in comments it is bad for readability here and too little space, use the [edit button](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58765222/edit) on the question to include it there

Comment: i've amended the post as per your requirement

Comment: check the path of the todoFunctions. I believe that is the error. based on the error, there is no route handler set up in your app

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because you have not defined any handler for `/`.

Try going to the `/tasks` instead in your browser, then you will get some response.